# Show icons in menues and buttons

Tags: menu

How do I enable icons in the menues (File-Edit-...) and also right-click-menues (Refresh-Copy-Paste-...) and on the buttons (OK-Cancel-Yes-No-...) in Ubuntu 11.10?
I would like it to work the way it does on Linux Mint or Zorin OS.
Cheers,
Kalsan

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command in a terminal:

```
gconftool --set /desktop/gnome/interface/menus_have_icons --type bool true
gconftool --set /desktop/gnome/interface/buttons_have_icons --type bool true
```

This will add the icons to the menus and the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer, different method:
Launch Ubuntu tweak (am using 0.8.6) and go to `tweaks` -> `Miscellaneous`,
Check the buttons `Menus have icons` and `Buttons have icons`.
This will also add the icons as above.