# how to get button icons on ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, icons

I have enabled the check mark for buttons-have-icons and menus-have-icons in gconf-editor as in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109456/show-icons-in-menues-and-buttons) post. These icons were visible in Ubuntu 12.04, but not in 13.04. What can I do to get back those? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then open **dconf-editor** and go to **org->gnome->desktop->interface**